# Does TensorFlow automatically parallelize independent computations in a loop when using autograph?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I have a function annotated with @tf.function.
That function contains a loop. Every loop iteration performs a certain complex computation by calling another @tf.function. The result of every computation is stored in a shared list, but the computations do not depend on the result of other computations and could therefore, in principle, be executed in parallel:

```
@tf.function
def outer_function(configuration):
    result = []
    for step in configuration.steps:
        result.append(inner_function(step, configuration))
    return result

@tf.function
def inner_function(step, configuration):
    # Do something complicated that does not depend on the result of other computations
    return ...
```

My question is: Does TensorFlow compute the result of each loop iteration in the outer function sequentially or in parallel?